# In iphone, cursor stays in its old place when keyboard pops up

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I cannot seem to find the css solution to this issue. I tried everything with `overflow` but nothing worked till now.

it happens only in ios, in android all is good.

any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with jquery, not optimal but it works

```
$('#password_id').on('focus', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am mentioning link of blog where you can get solution of your problem

Check out following link

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8

I think it may help you

Thank you

Comment: Welcome @doniyor

Answer (score 0):

This bug also affects iframe inputs, so I believe the fix I found will also help with modals.

All that needs to be done is to apply a the following css to the input within the iframe.

```
input:hover {
    cursor: text
}
```

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/ryanoutloud/project/full/AEKGjj